# I am new to Flutter, I try to run my project on Android Studio but I get an error in the console like:

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

```
  Future<String> getData() async {
http.Response response = await http.post(
Uri.encodeFull("https:.........."),
    headers: {
  "Accept" : "application/json"

}
,body: {
  "email" : "test123@gmail.com",
  "password" : "password123"
}
```

);

```
List data = JSON.decode(response.body);
print(data[0]["access_token"]);
```

}

```
ERROR:    '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously

```
JSON.decode(response.body);
```

returns a `Map` not a `List`

This

```
var data = JSON.decode(response.body);
```

or

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = JSON.decode(response.body);
```

should fix your error.